# DB2 Dynamic Load from cursor

Tags: db2, cursors, load

We have to load a number of huge tables using Load From cursor. The query formed for the same is a dynamic query as the column names are to be specified. we do the same using the below code in a procedure

```
For Mcnt As Mcur Cursor For 
  Select Di_tablename From file_mapping  Order By Id      
  Do


   For Mcnt1 As Mcur1 Cursor For Select Column_name  From Sysibm.Columns  Where Table_name=di_tablename 
   Do
       Set v_colquery = v_colquery || Column_name || ',' ;   
   End For;           

   Set v_colquery = Substr(v_colquery, 1, Length(v_colquery)-1);

 set v_sql ='LOAD FROM (SELECT '|| v_colquery || ' FROM ' || Di_tablename  || ' ) OF CURSOR INSERT INTO ' || Di_tablename || '_LOG  ( ' || v_colquery || ') NONRECOVERABLE';
call admin_cmd(v_sql);   
commit;

 END for;
```

The first round in loop executes just fine. But when it comes to the second it  gives the below error.

```
The cursor specified in a FETCH statement or CLOSE statement is not open or a cursor variable in a cursor scalar function reference is not open.. SQLCODE=-501, SQLSTATE=24501, DRIVER=4.18.60
```

All the cursors are implicit cursors(do correct me if  i am wrong). Unclear as to which cursor is being referenced and what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Also if i comment the Call to ADMIN_CMD  it runs without any issue.

Comment: `COMMIT` closes the cursor. You don't need that commit anyway, because the LOAD utility is not under transaction control.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! Any issues if I use cursor with hold? There are other statements that I will need to call in the same loop of this works fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because of *Commit* while using  *Cursor*.

Adding **WITH HOLD** to the cursor definition resolved the Issue.